# DNN Alert not working on DNN 7

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, dotnetnuke

I am using the 07.02.01 DNN Version

If I'm logged in with 'Super User Account', it works well. But if I'm not logged in or logged in with others accounts, it don't work.

I try adding the following 3 lines of code at the start of the `Page_Load` method.

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries.JavaScript.RequestRegistration(DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries.CommonJs.jQuery);
DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries.JavaScript.RequestRegistration(DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries.CommonJs.DnnPlugins);
DotNetNuke.UI.Utilities.ClientAPI.RegisterClientReference(this.Page, ClientAPI.ClientNamespaceReferences.dnn);
```

but `DotNetNuke.Framework` does not have a JavaScript library class and `DotNetNuke.UI.Utilities` does not have a ClientAPI class.

I added these 2 lines but still not working:

```
jQuery.RequestRegistration();
jQuery.RegisterScript(this.Page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure jQuery is loaded. When you logged in with a super user account jQuery is automatically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, and hopefully the solution I found will also help you.

My problem was, we have an in-house developed "Contact Us" button available on every page, which opens a popup with a Contact Us form, using `dnnModal.show`.

The problem stems from dnn.js not being loaded, which is needed for popups, and I think alerts, too.

Our solution was to add this to the `Page_Load` event:

```
ClientAPI.RegisterClientReference(Page, ClientAPI.ClientNamespaceReferences.dnn);
```

Remember to add your using/Import statement to import the `DotNetNuke.UI.Utilities` namespace. You also have to add `DotNetNuke.WebUtility` as a project reference.